# Is it possible for a method in ClassA to be triggered by an event in ClassB?

Tags: c#, oop, serial-port

I have a class called `Communicator` which has an interface to an `ElectronicDevice`, and `ElectronicDevice` has an interface to a `SerialPortWrapper` class (which in turn has a `SerialPort` object)

`Communicator` sends messages to the `ElectronicDevice` via the `SerialPort`.

`Communicator` needs to modify its behaviour in some cases based on the response from `SerialPort`. `SerialPort` would normally raise `SerialDataReceivedEvent` when its receives data, but `Communicator` doesn't have access to this.

What's the best way for me to deal with the communication between my objects and `SerialPort`? I'm open to any and all suggestions! (I'm completely new to communicating with the `SerialPort`, so if you can steer me correct, I really appreciate it!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SerialPortWrapper` could expose and raise an event when the `SerialPort` raises its event. Your `ElectronicDevice` could handle that event, and raise its own event. This will create a chain of events back to `Communicator`. At each stage along the way, you might choose to re-shape the event as appropriate - for example, `ElectronicDevice` might raise a `MessageReceived` event instead of a `SerialDataReceivedEvent`.

Comment: +1 for chaining rx data through SerialPortWrapper so that it can handle the SerialPort correctly without involving Communicator.